# Move block and set template

Tags: layout, xml, magento2.3, page-layouts

I succesfully moved the product related block in my page layout with

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.right" after='-'/>
```

I want now to apply a custom template to this block:

**product/list/mytemplate.phtml** instead of **product/list/items.phtml**
How can I do?

I tried adding also

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="product.review.related" template="product/list/items.phtml" />
```

but it don't works.

Comment: Than you, but not completely, see my new comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for Knowledge share: I used the following code to load related product collection and show results in a custom way (only "formato" field)

```
 <?php
$relatedProducts = $_product->getRelatedProductCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('formato');
?>          

<?php if ((count($relatedProducts)) != 0): ?>
<div class="altriformati">
    <h4 class="categorie">Altri formati disponibili:</h4>
    <?php foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {?>
    <a href="<?php echo $relatedProduct->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="acquista anche nel formato <?php echo $relatedProduct->getAttributeText('formato'); ?>">    
    <img src="<?php echo $store->getBaseUrl();  ?>pub/media/formati/<?php echo $relatedProduct->getAttributeText('formato'); ?>.png" alt="disponibile nel formato <?php echo $relatedProduct->getAttributeText('formato'); ?>" class="detail-icon"/>
    <?php echo $relatedProduct->getAttributeText('formato'); ?>
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>  
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try with **reference block** method.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.review.related">
<arguments>
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]_[Module]::product/list/items.phtml</argument>
</arguments>
```

In above **name=""** write your block identifier name. and **name=""** in argument pass tempalte.

Or you can set a template in the block file.

```
echo $this->getLayout()
      -createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related')
      ->setBlockId('product.review.related')
      ->toHtml();
```

Here I am sharing knowledge of how to set a custom template to block. template path and block identifier should be changed as per your requirement.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I tried the following code 
` <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related">
 <arguments>
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list/altriformati.phtml</argument>
 </arguments> 
 </referenceBlock> `
but template is always **Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml**
Here devtools results
**name**
catalog.product.related
**type**
block
**class**
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related
**template**
Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml
**module**
Magento_Catalog

Comment: Okay, nop. as per my answer I mentioned, I am sharing just knowledge. not an exact solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the specific Module location of your template:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="product.review.related" template="Vendor_Module::product/list/items.phtml" />
```